# How to classify singular points of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

Small debate between friends, how do you classify the singular points of the following function:

$$f(z) = \frac{z^3(z+1)}{1-z^4}$$

I found that the singular points are : $z=i, z=-i, z=1, z=-1$. Where both $z=i, z=-i, z=1$ are simple poles, $z=-1$ is a removable singularity.

However my friend says that $z=i ,z=-1$ are simple poles but $z=1, z=-1$ are poles of 2nd order.

Who is right or are we both wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: Your are right. Your friend is wrong.

Comment: You are right, $-1$ is removable while the other are simple poles

Comment: guess what guys, the friend is chatgpt. we have a fighting chance against the machines